# parse_ini_file() Как узнать отсутствие конфигурации

Tags: php

Вопрос из ряда - "Подводные камни".

Есть файл `conf.ini` который содержит много разных настроек которые используются в туче разных скриптов. Допустим вышло так что `Вася Пупкин` взял и по своей неопытности закомментировал или стер строку `a_z0_9 = az09` в следствии чего - сами понимаете что происходит.

Допустим строка a_z0_9 = az09 вызывается как:

```
echo $ini['a_z0_9']; // вместо a_z0_9 может быть все что угодно, т.к. заранее неизвестно что Вася умудрился стереть или закомментировать.
```

Есть ли возможность глобально отслеживать такие камешки имея только переменную `$ini` которой была вызвана функция `parse_ini_file()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот не нужно так делать.

нужно сделать функцию / метод через который получать нужные нам данные

аля:

```
function getIniVar($varName)
{
    static $INI_DATA;
    if (!isset($INI_DATA)) {
        $INI_DATA = parse_ini_file('conf.ini');
    }
    if (!empty($INI_DATA[$varName])) {
        return $INI_DATA[$varName];
    }
    add2Log('unseted var ['.$varName.']', 'ini_missed_keys');
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Никто и не делает ;) Вопрос на уровне спортивного интереса)

Comment: Никак, варианты на уровне set_error handler и парсить текст ошибки я не рассматриваю.

Comment: Через функцию уже давно написано, просто говорю же что спортивный интерес. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так: объявил бы в скрипте значения по умолчанию и "склеивал" бы их и конфигурацию после вытягивания данных:

```
$defaults = array(
    'abc' => 'abc',
    'a_z0_9' => 'somevalue',
);
$ini = parse_ini_file('conf.ini');
$ini = array_merge($defaults, $ini);
```